# Alterar repositório vinculado com projeto android no Git

Tags: android, android-studio, git

Bom dia, criei um projeto no Android Studio, criei um repositório no Git, fiz o Share do meu projeto no meu repositório.

Agora, gostaria de trocar de repositório, pegar esse meu projeto que já está vinculado e fazer ele vincular com outro repositório.

Como faço para trocar meu projeto de repositório no Android Studio ou de outro modo.

Comment: Queres apenas alterar o repositório remoto, isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alterar o remote do repositório no shell:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Para ver a url atual

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Espero ter ajudado

Fonte https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/